# How can I prefix cookies with __Host or __Secure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, ruby-on-rails-6, rack

I am trying to add [prefix to session cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#cookie_prefixes) in **rails 6.0.3** app but couldn't find a way to get it done. I have tried adding key to options hash in session store but it didn't help and breaks my application. I am using auth-logic gem for authentication, I find no way to get it done gracefully but hopping on that there is some way.

**conf/initalizers/session_store.rb**

```rb
opts = {}
if Rails.configuration.host == "myapplication.com"
  opts =  {expire_after: 2.months, domain: :all}
end

unless Rails.env.test?
  opts[:secure] = true
  opts[:same_site] = :none
end
opts[:key] = '__Host-'

Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, **opts
```

Attached is the screenshot of github cookies. I want my session headers as like in the image (prefixed with __Host-).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per your link...

> Cookies with the __Host- prefix must have a path of /
> (meaning any path at the host) and must not have a Domain attribute.

So I would presume you need to remove the `domain` attribute and add the `path`. e.g.

```
opts = {}
if Rails.configuration.host == "myapplication.com"
  opts =  {expire_after: 2.months}
end

unless Rails.env.test?
  opts[:secure] = true
  opts[:same_site] = :none
  opts[:path] = '/'
end
opts[:key] = '__Host-'

Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store, **opts
```

Comment: I am getting `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.` error with this solution

Comment: @Guillaume - you would need to raise your own question and provide the relevant information. The comments section isn't the place :)